# jQuery qTip load local PHP AJAX content with method GET

Tags: jquery, ajax, qtip

I just installed qTip on my webpage now I'm trying to understand how to load AJAX content on click of a link in a qTip. I'm novice in both jQuery and qTip so please bear with me.

I dynamically create (from MySQL database) links who looks something like this:

```
<a href='#' rel='717' class='qtip'>The link</a>
<a href='#' rel='718' class='qtip'>The link</a>
<a href='#' rel='719' class='qtip'>The link</a>
```

I would lke to send a `$_GET` to `loadqtip.php` and display the information from that page in my qtip.

Something like this i guess:

```
$("a.qtip").click(function() {

  var id = $(this).attr(rel);

  // send 'id' as GET to loadqtip.php and open the html result in qtip

});
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of carrying information in `rel` tag, you could use data-rel which can be accessed by [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of `.attr`.

```
<a href='#' data-rel='717' class='qtip'>The link</a>
```

Check how [jquery ajax](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.ajax) works.

```
$("a.qtip").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('rel');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'loadqtip.php',
        data: 'id=' + id,
        success: function(data) {
            //do your stuff
        }
    });
});​
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `s/rel/'rel'` - even though using `data-` attributes for it would be a better idea.

Comment: Thank's. You'r code generates "illegal character": `});​` though, but I cant see why? i added `alert(data);` inside the `success:` function.

Comment: well as i see it, the code here is fine, may be you could do a demo on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)